# Inserção de intervalos com a estrutura de condição if else

Tags: r

Considere o vetor e a função:

```
j <- 1:10

my_fun <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(x) {
    if (x == 5) {
      ('EM ANALISE')
    } else if (x < 5) {
      ('REPROVADO')
    } else if (x > 5) {
      ('APROVADO')
    }
  })
}

my_fun(j)

 [1] "REPROVADO"  "REPROVADO"  "REPROVADO"  "REPROVADO"  "EM ANALISE" "APROVADO"  
 [7] "APROVADO"   "APROVADO"   "APROVADO"   "APROVADO"
```

Como selecionar o intervalo entre `3` e `4.9` e inserir a categoria `RECUPERAÇÃO`, de forma que o resultado fique:

```
[1] "REPROVADO"  "REPROVADO" "RECUPERAÇÃO" "RECUPERAÇÃO" "EM ANALISE" "APROVADO"  
[7] "APROVADO"   "APROVADO"   "APROVADO"   "APROVADO"
```

Além disso, como usar um `for` ao invés de `sapply` e obter o mesmo resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não são necessários `if` nem ciclos `for` ou `*apply`.
Aqui vão duas maneiras de fazer o que quer.

**1.** Pode-se usar o `cut`.

```
my_fun2 <- function(x){
  menor_que_5 <- 5 - .Machine$double.eps^0.5
  brks <- c(-Inf, 3, menor_que_5, 5, Inf)
  labs <- c('REPROVADO', 'RECUPERAÇÃO', 'EM ANALISE', 'APROVADO')
  res <- cut(x, breaks = brks, labels = labs, 
             include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)
  as.character(res)
}

my_fun2(1:10)
```

**2.** Outra maneira é usar o `findInterval`.

```
my_fun3 <- function(x){
  menor_que_5 <- 5 - .Machine$double.eps^0.5
  brks <- c(-Inf, 3, menor_que_5, 5, Inf)
  labs <- c('REPROVADO', 'RECUPERAÇÃO', 'EM ANALISE', 'APROVADO')
  i <- findInterval(x, brks)
  labs[i]
}

my_fun3(1:10)
```

**3.** Agora com `ifelse`.

```
my_fun4 <- function(x) {
  menor_que_5 <- 5 - .Machine$double.eps^0.5
  ifelse (x == 5, 'EM ANALISE',
          ifelse(x < 3, 'REPROVADO',
                 ifelse(x < menor_que_5, 'RECUPERAÇÃO', 'APROVADO')))
}

my_fun4(1:10)
```

**4.** E finalmente com um ciclo `for`.

```
my_fun5 <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  y <- character(n)
  for(i in seq_len(n)){
    y[i] <- if (x[i] < 3) {
      'REPROVADO'
    } else if (x[i] < 5) {
      'RECUPERAÇÃO'
    } else if (x[i] == 5) {
      'EM ANALISE'
    } else if (x[i] > 5) {
      'APROVADO'
    }
  }
  y
}

my_fun5(1:10)
```

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, Rui. Mas, por necessidade, preciso resolver este problema nestas condições.

Comment: @user108927 Feito, com `ifelse` e com `for`.